# Loop through dataframe to change a columns values - python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with a column of Months. The months are in their numeric values, i.e 1 through to 12. I need these to read as their actual text equivalent, such that 1 would be replaced with January and 2 would be replaced with February and so on.

At the minute I'm doing it the long way by declaring each month separately:

```
cntryPerMonth.loc[cntryPerMonth['Month'] == 1.0, 'Month'] = 'January'
cntryPerMonth.loc[cntryPerMonth['Month'] == 2.0, 'Month'] = 'February'
cntryPerMonth.loc[cntryPerMonth['Month'] == 3.0, 'Month'] = 'March'
cntryPerMonth.loc[cntryPerMonth['Month'] == 4.0, 'Month'] = 'April'
cntryPerMonth.loc[cntryPerMonth['Month'] == 5.0, 'Month'] = 'May'
and so on for the remaining months
```

Is there a more efficient way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to replace the values:

```
replace_dict = {
    1:'Jan', 2:'Feb'
}


df = pd.DataFrame({'month': [1,2]})

df['month_names'] = df['month'].replace(replace_dict)
```